# React Native Android - gradlew assembleRelease command unable to generate apk output

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, react-native, apk

I am currently using React Native for my android app. The version of RN is 0.46.1 and the CLI is 2.0.1. Gradle as according to my Android Studio is version 3.3.

I managed to install my app into Android Emulator using "react-native run-android" without much issue. It works fine, but when I tried to generate apk, I got some errors. I am running on Windows 10.

Commands executed:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \ --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \ --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

cd android && gradlew assembleRelease
```

Right after 2nd command above, I got some errors:

```
:app:mergeReleaseResources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_disabled] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_disabled.png      [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_disabled] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_disabled.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_travel022] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_travel022.jpg    [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_travel022] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_travel022.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png        [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_up128] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_up128.png        [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_up128] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_up128.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png  [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_openenvelopewithletter_31832670] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_openenvelopewithletter_31832670.jpg      [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_openenvelopewithletter_31832670] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_openenvelopewithletter_31832670.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png  [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_down128] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_down128.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_down128] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_down128.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_enabled] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_enabled.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_enabled] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_enabled.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_weather1gif] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_weather1gif.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_weather1gif] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_weather1gif.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_back_chevron] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_back_chevron.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_back_chevron] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_back_chevron.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_accommodation_icon1] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_accommodation_icon1.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_accommodation_icon1] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_accommodation_icon1.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_noimage] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_noimage.gif    [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_noimage] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_noimage.gif: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png  [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_itineraryicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_itineraryicon.png      [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_itineraryicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_itineraryicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativedatepicker_date_icon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativedatepicker_date_icon.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativedatepicker_date_icon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativedatepicker_date_icon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png    [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png    [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png        [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_travelguide] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_travelguide.jpg    [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_travelguide] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_travelguide.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_menu_burger] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_menu_burger.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_menu_burger] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_menu_burger.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_embedplacesicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_embedplacesicon.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_embedplacesicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_embedplacesicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_diningicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_diningicon.png      [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_diningicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_diningicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
:app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_disabled] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_disabled.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_disabled] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_disabled.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_travel022] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_travel022.jpg    [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_travel022] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_travel022.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png        [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_up128] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_up128.png        [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_up128] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_up128.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png  [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_openenvelopewithletter_31832670] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_openenvelopewithletter_31832670.jpg      [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_openenvelopewithletter_31832670] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_openenvelopewithletter_31832670.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png  [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_down128] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_down128.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_down128] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_down128.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_enabled] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_enabled.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_enabled] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativecheckbox_cb_enabled.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_weather1gif] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_weather1gif.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_weather1gif] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_weather1gif.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_back_chevron] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_back_chevron.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_back_chevron] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_back_chevron.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_accommodation_icon1] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_accommodation_icon1.png  [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_accommodation_icon1] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_accommodation_icon1.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_noimage] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_noimage.gif    [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_noimage] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_noimage.gif: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png  [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_itineraryicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_itineraryicon.png      [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_itineraryicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_itineraryicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativedatepicker_date_icon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativedatepicker_date_icon.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativedatepicker_date_icon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativedatepicker_date_icon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png    [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png    [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativegoogleplacesautocomplete_images_powered_by_google_on_white.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png        [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_travelguide] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_travelguide.jpg    [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_travelguide] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_travelguide.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativeexperimentalnavigation_assets_back.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_menu_burger] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_menu_burger.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_menu_burger] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\node_modules_reactnativerouterflux_src_menu_burger.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_embedplacesicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_embedplacesicon.png    [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_embedplacesicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_embedplacesicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_diningicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\assets_diningicon.png      [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_diningicon] D:\travelogue\FE27\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\assets_diningicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 20.5 secs
```

I found some forums discussing similar problems https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787 but it doesn't really solve the problem (tried removing generated output files, even trie snippet code as suggested in the forum).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. Here is how I fixed it. This is the most complex and robust way - see the end for easier options.

1. Renamed all my `android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*` folders, adding a `-v4` to them all. (After this they look like: `drawable-xhdpi-v4`, `drawable-ldpi-v4`, etc.) Note: don't change the `drawable` folder itself.
2. Add a post-install hook to package.json that fixes the `node_modules/react-native/local-cli/bundle/assetPathUtils.js` file by adding `-v4` to all of the switch statement's return values. The resulting switch statement in the assetPathUtils.js file should look like this:

   ```
   switch (scale) {
       case 0.75: return 'ldpi-v4';
       case 1: return 'mdpi-v4';
       case 1.5: return 'hdpi-v4';
       case 2: return 'xhdpi-v4';
       case 3: return 'xxhdpi-v4';
       case 4: return 'xxxhdpi-v4';
   }
   ```

This is one way to write that post-install hook:

```
const sh = require('shelljs');
const fileToFix =
    'node_modules/react-native/local-cli/bundle/assetPathUtils.js';
const replacements = [
    ["case 0.75: return 'ldpi';", "case 0.75: return 'ldpi-v4';"],
    ["case 1: return 'mdpi';", "case 1: return 'mdpi-v4';"],
    ["case 1.5: return 'hdpi';", "case 1.5: return 'hdpi-v4';"],
    ["case 2: return 'xhdpi';", "case 2: return 'xhdpi-v4';"],
    ["case 3: return 'xxhdpi';", "case 3: return 'xxhdpi-v4';"],
    ["case 4: return 'xxxhdpi';", "case 4: return 'xxxhdpi-v4';"],
];
const content = sh.cat(fileToFix).stdout;
const fixedContent = replacements.reduce(
    (accumulator, [oldStr, newStr]) => accumulator.replace(oldStr, newStr),
    content
);
sh.ShellString(fixedContent).to(fileToFix);
```

And registering it in your package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./postinstall.js",
...
```

### Other fixes from the [5787 issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5787):

- If you don't have any custom icons in your `drawable-*` folders then you should be able to delete them all and have things work that way. (this is one I haven't personally confirmed)
- If you don't need to use gradle v3+, then downgrading back to gradle v2.* will resolve the issue - although Android studio will continually prompt you to upgrade gradle.